# Jenkins - Updating build changelog during build step

Tags: jenkins

I noticed that if you use Jenkins with the SVN or CVS option, a changelog.xml is created for each build that contains the author and the commit message for that build.

Unfortunately, in my setup, I am not using SVN or CVS, so I am unable to take advantage of the changelog parser.  I was wondering if it was possible to create your own changelog with the same format (like the SVN XML changelog) and then point Jenkins to it during the build process.  This way, when someone clicks on changes for the build, they'll be able to see what changed and who changed it.

I've tried just creating a changelog.xml and then updating build.xml to use the SVN parser, but two issues that I've noticed:
1) You have to reload configuration files to get it to show up
2) Build.xml doesn't appear to be created until the job is complete

There is some information on the changelog parser, but it doesn't seem that you can just access it during a build step: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+log

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a **system groovy scripts** would be a good direction (groovy script plugin). Just add a new script as your build step. You can access your AbstractBuild object by running the following code:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*
import hudson.scm.*

def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
```

I'm trying to solve a similar problem currently, but my use case change a bit. I try to copy the changes from Upstream project in the similar way that **BlameSubversion** plugin does. Unfortunately I can't use the mentioned above SCM plugin because it doesn't work with post-commit-hook, so I have to write my own solution.

Take a look at copyChangeLogFromTriggerJob and copyRevisionFromTriggerJob methods to get know how BlameSubversion does that.

I'm able to copy changes and revision but I'm still fighting with ChangeLogParser. 
I would be gladfull for any help as well.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to give that a try.  I'm curious if I can update the object to use the SVN ChangeLogParser when I'm not using SVN.  I'll hopefully get the chance to try this out in the next few days.  Thanks!